# Looking to validate both textField and comboBox in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, validation, combobox, textfield

Please be gentle, this is my first time working with Swing and GUI's.

**My problem/question:**

I have written some code using Java Swing GUI. The validation portion of my code will only recognize if the textField is incorrectly filled out and ignores if the comboBoxes are left empty. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? My goal is to make sure that all fields are filled out when the user hits submit. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpecs;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FeliciasStore_GUI extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FeliciasStore_GUI frame = new FeliciasStore_GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public FeliciasStore_GUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 558, 364);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Size:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(67, 39, 23, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.setBounds(96, 36, 161, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
    comboBox.addItem("Small");
    comboBox.addItem("Medium");
    comboBox.addItem("Large");
    comboBox.addItem("XLarge");
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);

    JLabel lblColor = new JLabel("Color:");
    lblColor.setBounds(61, 90, 29, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblColor);

    JComboBox<String> comboBox_1 = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox_1.setBounds(96, 87, 161, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox_1);
    comboBox_1.addItem("Blue");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Red");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Silver");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Gold");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Aqua");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Green");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Pink");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Purple");
    comboBox_1.addItem("White");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Black");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Orange");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Maroon");
    comboBox_1.setSelectedItem(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBounds(518, 122, 19, 0);
    contentPane.add(label);

    JLabel lblStyle = new JLabel("Style:");
    lblStyle.setBounds(62, 141, 28, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblStyle);


    JComboBox<String> comboBox_2 = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox_2.setBounds(96, 138, 161, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox_2);
    comboBox_2.addItem("Queen");
    comboBox_2.addItem("King");
    comboBox_2.addItem("Pawn");
    comboBox_2.addItem("Knight");
    comboBox_2.addItem("Joker");
    comboBox_2.addItem("Babydoll");
    comboBox_2.addItem("Superstar");
    comboBox_2.setSelectedItem(null);

    JLabel lblInscription = new JLabel("Inscription:");
    lblInscription.setBounds(36, 192, 54, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblInscription);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(96, 189, 161, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnSubmit_1 = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    btnSubmit_1.setBounds(96, 240, 161, 23);
    btnSubmit_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(textField.getText().length()>15 || comboBox == null || comboBox_1 == null || comboBox_2 == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Insufficient input.", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            String enscription = textField.getText();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnSubmit_1);
}

}
```

Comment: Probably `combobox.getSelectedItem()== null || comboBox_1.getSelectedItem() == null || comboBox_2.getSelectedItem() == null`?

Comment: Thanks!!! That worked perfectly! The program is now acting as desired!

Comment: `this is my first time working with Swing and GUI's.` - don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).